# Given Two Arrays A & B , find the first number in both arrays such that replacing them makes the sum of array A equal to sum of array B

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

Lets consider

```
A = [1,7,9,10] sumA = 27
B = [0,10,9,6] sumB = 25
```

Find first elements(if present) from A and B such that if we replace A[i] with B[j]. sumA = sumB

Here, if we replace 1 with 0.

```
sumA=sumB=26
```

I know the brute force O(n2) solution. But a better solution,like O(n) is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "*swap* `1` with `0`"? If you leave the `0` in `B` alone the sum of `B` is still `25`. Also, can you assume that `A` and `B` are sorted? (`B` is not sorted in your example.)

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? If A[0] B[5], A[5] B[0] and A[1] B[1] are all valid replacements, how would you order those, i.e. which one would be the correct answer (and why)?

Comment: [Find two element a and b from set A and B such that on swapping these elements, sum of sets is equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44193865/find-two-element-a-and-b-from-set-a-and-b-such-that-on-swapping-these-elements?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an `O(n)` solution that involves hashing the values of one of the arrays; since for each element, `a`, in array `A` there is only one possible element, `b`, in array `B` that would solve the question:

```
sumA - a + b = sumB - b + a

2*b = sumB - sumA + 2*a

b = (sumB - sumA) / 2 + a
```

Hash the values of `B` in `O(n)` and for each element, `a`, in `A`, determine in `O(1)` if the value `(sumB - sumA) / 2 + a` exists in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

**O(nlogn)** complexity, **O(n)** memory solution:

Given the initial arrays `A` and `B`, `sumA-sumB` is twice the difference of the swapped elements. If `sumA-sumB` is odd, there is no solution. If `sumA-sumB` is even (in the example, it is equal to 2), we might proceed.

Now sort both arrays (if you can't do it in-place, construct sorted arrays somewhere nearby, hence **O(n)** memory) in **O(nlogn)** time. Once the arrays are sorted, you might scan them simultaneously in **O(n)** time, maintaining the invariant: iterator to `sortedB` always points to an element that's at least `(sumA-sumB)/2` less than this of `sortedA` iterator. Drive `sortedA` iterator forward, bump `sortedB` iterator as needed - the traversal somewhat resembles merge sort. Once you find values in two arrays that differ by exactly `(sumA-sumB)/2` - stop the traversal, fall back to original arrays and find these values (and their indices) - this is your solution. If the traversal does not find an exact match - there is no solution.

If the initial arrays are sorted, the complexity is reduced to **O(n)** time, **O(1)** memory.

Comment: Because otherwise looking for matching numbers (namely, differing by `(sumA-sumB)/2`) will take O(n^2)

Comment: @RoryDaulton note that OP said nothing about the language, nor did he mention `python` tag in his previous questions. Also, considering the algorithms theory, lists and arrays are different data structures. Also, considering sofrware engineering, unconditionnaly sorting something in-place (especially considering the explicit requirement to work with the unmodified data later) is a no-go.